# Why does implicit date casting to [string] not use current regional settings?

Tags: powershell, powershell-7.3

PowerShell does an implicit conversion of a [datetime] to [string] in order to do this concatenation.

Why does using `ToString()` use the current regional settings while not using it produces a different result?

```
PS C:\> 'now ' + (Get-Date).AddDays(-3)
now 06/10/2023 12:32:28
PS C:\> 'now ' + (Get-Date).AddDays(-3).ToString()
now 2023-06-10 12:32:47

PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.3.4
```

Related question: [Why is Powershell Write-Output Date Format not the System Setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40150940/447901)

Comment: It appears that the PowerShell team is a bit en-us oriented. Being ISO-8601 oriented might be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.ToString()` will call the [`DateTime.ToString()` instance method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tostring?view=net-7.0#system-datetime-tostring) which uses the current culture, where as casting will use whatever the PowerShell team decided to use for `IFormatProvider`.

<strike>I believe the code in charge of this is [`LanguagePrimitives.ConvertTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.languageprimitives.convertto?view=powershellsdk-7.3.0)</strike>, which by the looks of it, they decided to use `InvariantCulture`: [LanguagePrimitives.cs#L1758C2-L1766](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/9a358f26f0dd80044513ed2651fff0311f301fcf/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/LanguagePrimitives.cs#L1758C2-L1766).

```bash
# Both produce the same DateTime format string
[System.Management.Automation.LanguagePrimitives]::ConvertTo(
    (Get-Date).AddDays(-3),
    [string])

(Get-Date).AddDays(-3).ToString([cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)
```

Type casting is actually handled by [PSConvertBinder](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/00ce2a47dc704a5aa27316032322e0e41cc6c03a/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Binding/Binders.cs#L3734) and they're also using `InvariantCulture` there: [Binders.cs#L3765-L3795](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/00ce2a47dc704a5aa27316032322e0e41cc6c03a/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/runtime/Binding/Binders.cs#L3765-L3795). [ScriptBlockDisassembler Module](https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/ScriptBlockDisassembler) makes it really easy to understand what internal classes are being used:

```cs
PS ..\pwsh> { [string] [datetime]::Now } | Get-ScriptBlockDisassembly -Minimal

// ScriptBlock.EndBlock
try
{
    funcContext._outputPipe.Add(
        Fake.Dynamic<Func<CallSite, DateTime, string>>(PSConvertBinder.Get(typeof(string)))(DateTime.Now));
}
catch (FlowControlException)
{
    throw;
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(funcContext, exception);
}
```

Comment: It might be helpful it the datetime format in `[cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture` was ISO-8601.

Comment: Nicely done; I assume that `Get-ScriptBlockDisassembly` is from the third-party [`ScriptBlockDisassembler` module](https://github.com/SeeminglyScience/ScriptBlockDisassembler). @lit, to get ISO 8601 format, you can use `(Get-Date).ToString('o')` for instance, and this format is also recognized by the invariant culture, and therefore in _casts_; e.g. `[datetime] (Get-Date).ToString('o')`

Comment: @lit, for a (hopefully) comprehensive overview of when string operations in PowerShell are culture-sensitive and when not, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).